# Error - Incorrect Username or password - Glue connection to Snowflake

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue of "incorrect username or password" issue while executing ETL job. I am 100% sure that I have provided the correct username and password and given the right jdbc , spark jar files. Is there any specific format we need to provide password or username in the job parameters, like double quotes or braces or anything specific. :

### Parameters:

[image: Job parameters]

### Job Script:

```
  import sys
  from awsglue.transforms import *
  from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
  from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  from awsglue.context import GlueContext
  from awsglue.job import Job
  from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
  SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

  ## @params: [JOB_NAME, URL, ACCOUNT, WAREHOUSE, DB, SCHEMA, USERNAME, PASSWORD]
  args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'URL', 'ACCOUNT', 'WAREHOUSE', 'DB', 'SCHEMA', 
 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'])
  sc = SparkContext()
  glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
  spark = glueContext.spark_session
  job = Job(glueContext)
  job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
  java_import(spark._jvm, "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")

  ## uj = sc._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake

  spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.enablePushdownSession 
  (spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())
  sfOptions = {
      "sfUrl" : args['URL'],
      "sfaccount" : args['ACCOUNT'],
      "sfDatabase" : args['DB'],
      "sfSchema" : args['SCHEMA'],
      "sfWarehouse" : args['WAREHOUSE'],
      "sfUser" : args['USERNAME'],
      "sfPassword" : args['PASSWORD'],
    }

  dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "salesforcedb", table_name = 
  "pr_summary_csv", transformation_ctx = "dyf")
  df=dyf.toDF()
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("temptable")
  sql_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temptable")
  sql_df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("dbtable", 
  "abcdef").option("parallelism",8).mode("overwrite").save()
```

Comment: Hi, Could somebody provide your thoughts on the above post. I have been trying for 1 week now  to resolve this issues, but in vain. Any kind of assistance will be of great relief to me. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using JDBC and solved it by separating account and region.

```
sfaccount = mna71142
sfRegion = us-east-1
```